# Use cases for Modules in the Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

Besides the obvious 'admin' and 'blog' use cases for a module structure in Zend Framework are there any reasons or guidelines to use Modules?  I feel drawn to use modules, but I'm not sure how I would split my web app up into modules.

Can you suggestion some instances where using modules would be beneficial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are good when you want to reuse them across multiple applications, or when a piece of the application is large enough that it warrants separation into its own chunk. Rather than having a bunch of unrelated controllers in one directory, the module allows you to split up the MVCs into related chunks.

We use modules all the time; our clients frequently pick and choose between the available modules to package an application. We also introduced module dependencies, so that modules may rely on each other.

As a general rule, when our applications have a high level subfolder, unless they have only a couple pages, they are modules. For example, About would only be a controller and a view within the application, but forum might be its own module.